# `with` statement in python is different from pep343

Tags: python

The code below with `with` statement runs successfully.

```
class A(object):

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, et, ev, tb):
        print 1

a = A()

class B(object):

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    __exit__ = a.__exit__

b = B()

# ok here, without any error
with b:
    print 2
```

However, if we translate `with` statement into the code based on [pep343](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/#specification-the-with-statement), there will be an error.

```
import sys

mgr   = b
exit  = type(mgr).__exit__
value = type(mgr).__enter__(mgr)
exc   = True
try:
    try:
        print 1
    except:
        exc = False
        if not exit(mgr, *sys.exc_info()):
            raise
finally:
    if exc:
        exit(mgr, None, None, None)
```

Because `type(b).__exit__(a, None, None, None)` equals `A.__exit__(a, a, None, None, None)`, the error is caused by too many parameters.

My question is

- why is the `with` statement in python different from pep343
- what is the real standard of `with` statement or context manager in python

Comment: What do you mean by "why is the with statement in python different from pep343" ? The `as` part is optional if that's what you meant: *The "as VAR" part is optional*. Secondly you're assigning `__exit__` to an instance method `a.__exit__` instead of `A.__exit__`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary If you run two pieces of code, you will find the first is successful, but the second is wrong. However, based pep343, the two is same. This makes me confuse.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary `a.__exit__` and `A.__exit__` will cause different results in second piece of code because `a.__exit__` is bound method and `A.__exit__` is unbound method. Am I right?

Comment: Correct you are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting this error is that you're assigning an instance method from `A` to `B`'s `__exit__`, this results in too many arguments because you're passing the instance again with `exit`: `exit(mgr, None, None, None)`, and it being a bound method, it will append the instance again resulting in too many arguments.

Hence, you can get rid of `mgr` argument from the `exit` calls.

Based on your code:

```
In [21]: B.__exit__.__self__
Out[21]: <__main__.A at 0x110bb65d0>

In [22]: A.__exit__.__self__
Out[22]: None
```